# Recursion over an array of object to create custom class object

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, javascript-objects

I have an javascript array of object containing some parameters to be passed to custom class.

```
    var classObjectDetails = [{
      name: "objOne",
      options: ["1","2"],
      children: [{
        name: "childOne_objOne",
        options: null
        children: [{
          name: "childOne_childOne_objOne",
          options: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        }]
      }, {
        name: "childTwo_objOne",
        options: null,
      }]
    }, {
      name: "objTwo",
      options: null,
    }];
```

Above is sample object containing details. If i have a class like below,

```
class sampleClass {
  constructor(objName, option) {
      this.name = objName;
      this.options = option;
      this.children = [];
      // Some other properties
    }
    // Some other functions
}
```

I want to write an efficient recursive function which in the end return me the array of sampleClass object.

objOne and objTwo being two object in array, with objOne having two children and so on as given in the `classObjectDetails`

Comment: Try, fail, post it here. At least make a loop in a function calling itself.

Comment: Can you please post the expected output?

Comment: I have tried doing it with forEach but that won't work without code change if the nesting of children increase further. Also i tried to iterate over outer array then parse through each one but i wasn't able to parse after third level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create recursive function using `forEach()` loop and use data from each object in original array to create instance of your class that will have all methods of that class.

```js
var data = [{"name":"objOne","options":["1","2"],"children":[{"name":"childOne_objOne","options":null,"children":[{"name":"childOne_childOne_objOne","options":["a","b","c","d"]}]},{"name":"childTwo_objOne","options":null}]},{"name":"objTwo","options":null}]

class sampleClass {
  constructor(objName, option) {
    this.name = objName;
    this.options = option;
    this.children = [];
  }
  
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

function create(data) {
  var result = [];
  data.forEach(function(e) {
    var o = new sampleClass;
    o.name = e.name;
    o.options = e.options
    if (e.children) {
      var children = create(e.children)
      if (children.length) o.children = children;
    }
    result.push(o)
  })
  return result;
}

var result = create(data);
console.log(result)
console.log(result[0].children[0].getName())
```

Comment: Thanks, i was having problem with that parsing children. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var classObjectDetails = [
    {
      name: "objOne",
      options: ["1","2"],
      children: [
      {
        name: "childOne_objOne",
        options: null,
        children: [
            {
              name: "childOne_childOne_objOne",
              options: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "childTwo_objOne",
        options: null,
      }
      ]
    }, 

    {
      name: "objTwo",
      options: null,
    }];

function parseJSONTosampleClass(classObjectDetail){
    var sampleClasList = [];
    for (var key in classObjectDetail) {
        var child = classObjectDetail[key];
        var obj = new sampleClass();
        sampleClasList.push(obj);
        obj.name = child["name"];
        obj.options = child["options"];
        obj.children = parseJSONTosampleClass(child["children"]);
    }

    return sampleClasList;
}
class sampleClass {
constructor(objName, option) {
      this.name = objName;
      this.options = option;
      this.children = [];
    }
}

parseJSONTosampleClass(classObjectDetails);

</script>
```